# Datetime conversion problem in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl, locale

I have a flat file with the following format as datetime

`5/3/22 2:09:02 PM (MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS)` but it gets read in SQL Server as `2022-03-05 14:09:02`. I have used SSIS ETL to load the flatfile to DB.

How to fix this error? I was supposed to get `2022-05-03 14:09:02` in SQL Server. Suggest me the datatype as well

Comment: You may well be better off using a staging table to `INSERT` the data into, then you can `CONVERT` the value with an explicit [style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles) code for the format your data is in when you `INSERT` it into your production table.

Comment: As for the data type, `datetime2(0)`? What [Date and Time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-types-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time) data type you need depends on *your* requirements, and we don't know what those are.

Comment: For your kind reference am adding the flatfile here. My problem is For the first half of the data is getting reflected with the correct date time format and the other half is with the wrong format. Here am attaching the sample raw data here.                                                   6/30/22 11:59:07 PM;123.456478956215;
7/1/22 12:00:46 AM;128.4670934721739;

Comment: Another option might be to use a [script component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/script-component?view=sql-server-ver16) then you can leverage [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=net-6.0) to specify a format, e.g `Row.OuputDateTimeColumn = DateTime.ParseExact(Row.InputDateTimeColumn,"MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a locale problem. It looks like your flat file has its dates encoded according to the American method and your database default locale is set to some European method.

When you set up your SSIS job, pick an American locale (US English will work) in the flat file connector properties panel. Then SSIS will handle your input date/time values the way you want.